# Views Secondary Group

Tags: views, entities

I have a View which is a list of stores and for each store I have a list of products. This is a sample as it looks now:

```
Ken's Store

Products: Doodles
Products: Daddles

Joe's Store

Products: Acme Hammer
Products: Acme Nails
```

Stores are a content type and products are a content type. Products has an entity reference to stores. The view is set to Unformatted list and grouping by Content title(store). I'd like the view to group products like this:

```
Ken's Store

Products:
Doodles
Daddles

Joe's Store

Products:
Acme Hammer
Acme Nails
```

Setting Content Title (products) as the second grouping field only causes a repetitive title without grouping. **How do I get the products to group under the store grouping?**

Answer (score 0):

You can set grouping after any field in the view at the format settings. This should work for this.